# Turn Camera Light in Android API 22

Tags: android

I've write simple example to turn on/turn off camera light

My code working 100% in Android API 21 but in HTC One Plus API 22 camera light don't turn on

My code :

```
if (!isFlashOn)
        {
            if (camera == null || mParams == null) {
                return;
            }
            _player.Start();
            mParams = camera.GetParameters();
            mParams.FlashMode = Parameters.FlashModeTorch;
            camera.SetParameters(mParams);
            camera.StartPreview();
            isFlashOn = true;
            btnFlash.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.power_on);

        }
```

Comment: try to check if FlashModeTorch exists in HTC, maybe you need to change it according to device

Comment: Make sure you are asking for camera permission on runtime.

Comment: Thanks all , i've done with Ashish Ranjan's solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
camera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters mParams = camera.getParameters();
mParams.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
camera.setParameters(mParams);
mPreviewTexture = new SurfaceTexture(0);
try {
   camera.setPreviewTexture(mPreviewTexture);
} catch (IOException ex) {
   // ioexception
}
camera.startPreview();
```

Also make sure you've camera permissions in your manifest file.

Comment: happy to help! you can mark the answer as correct so that others can benefit from the answer.